# Use an Image Collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze

I'm building a Meteor app that communicates with a desktop client via HTTP requests with https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi

The desktop client generates images at irregular time intervals, and I want the Meteor site to only display the most recently generated image (ideally in real time). My initial idea was to use a PUT request to a singleton collection with the base64 imagedata, but I don't know how to turn that data into an image in the web browser. Note: the images are all pretty small (much less than 1 MB) so using gridFS should be unnecessary.

I realize this idea could be completely wrong, so if I'm completely on the wrong track, please suggest a better course of action.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write a middleware to serve your images with proper MIME type. Example:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice (0, 0, {
  route: '/imageserver',
  handle: function(req, res, next) {

    // Assuming the path is /imageserver/:id, here you get the :id
    var iid = req.url.split('/')[1];

    var item = Images.findOne(iid);

    if(!item) {
      // Image not found
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end('File not found');
      return;
    }

    // Image found
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': item.type,
    });
    res.write(new Buffer(item.data, 'base64'));
    res.end();

  },

});
```